# For 3 straights $l_1,l_2,l_3$ in a 2-dimensional projective space $P(V)$ so that they don’t intersect. How can I prove the following statement:

Tags: projective-geometry, projective-space, duality-theorems

Given 3 straight lines $l_1,l_2,l_3$ in a 2-dimensional projective space $P(V)$ so that for two on two lines: $l_i \cap l_j=\emptyset$
And $\{V_i\vert i=1,2,3\}\subset V $ and $l_i= P(V_i)$

Can somebody help me with my proof of the following statement:

1. prove that $\forall x\in l_1:\exists! y\in l_2 \wedge \exists! z\in l_3: x,y,z $ are collineair

**what I have tried so far: I have chosen a base $\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}$ for V. Then defined the parameter equations: $l_i \leftrightarrow V_i \leftrightarrow x=\lambda_{0,i}v_0+\lambda_{1,i}v_1+\lambda_{2,i}v_2$ Then I thought to prove that statement in $\mathbb{E}^3$? Such as: take $x\in V_1$. Because $l_1,l_2, l_3$ are hyperplanes in the projective plane $\mathbb{R}P^2$, they have to be hyperplanes and  therefore planes in $\mathbb{E}^3$, and because $$V_1 \cap V_2 \cap V_3 = \emptyset \implies V_1^{\perp}=V_2^{\perp}=V_2^{\perp}$$and therefore we find that all planes have the same orthogonal vector $$(a_0,a_1,a_2)$$ and thus also the same cartesian-equation in the projective space: $$P(V_i)=l_i\leftrightarrow 0=a_0x_0+a_1x_1+a_2x_2$$ now I wanted to define a plane $$V_\perp \leftrightarrow x + vct\{(a_0,a_1,a_2),b\}$$with (b the vector between x and the origin). Since the intersection between each plane $V_i$ and that perpendicular plane $V_\perp$ would be 3 parallel lines, and then each straight would be represented as a point in the projective space which would lay then on the same projective line ($l_\perp=P(V_\perp))$**

I ended up stuck in this problem. I would appreciate very much some help to make me understand the nature of this problem and how I can prove that statement on this manner, and also if there was an alternative way through the use of duality?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please clarify the question. Does  'straight' mean 'line'? In 2-dimensional projective space, 2 distinct lines intersect in exactly one point.

Comment: Yes, I mean lines. Sorry for the confusion

Comment: This probably is about lines in a $3$ dimensional projective space, such that any $2$ do not intersect.  So you work in $\mathbb{R}P^3$,( or $P^3(k)$ , $k$ a field )

Comment: @orangeskid V is 3 dimensional Vector space, and P(V) is a 2 dimensional projective space.